# ArcGIS Survey123 - Selecting a point on a map to collect data about

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, arcgis-survey123

I am new to ArcGIS and survey123 but I have some experience working with QGIS and ODK and xlsforms.

I have a map with point features that represent buildings (each point represents a building location). I have the maps in QGIS; however, I want to export them in order to be used in survey123. (We don’t have ArcGIS at the moment but we will get it soon).

When we go into the field, we want to have an offline map which visualizes all the points that represent the buildings. I want to be able to move out in the field and navigate to these point features. I also want to be able to edit/add their characteristics in the field so the enumerator can click the point and fill a form (number of floors, types, etc.).

In addition, I want the enumerator to be able to add additional points, if necessary, in the field. For example, if there is a new building that wasn’t in the map, I want the enumerator to add a point on the map and fill the form.

Is it possible to do it in survey123? What tools do I need?
I am sorry if it is an obvious question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survey123 is ESRI's form-centric app (no map interface). Their map-centric app is/was called [Collector for ArcGIS](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-collector/overview), which is being superseded by [ArcGIS Field Maps](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-field-maps/overview) (I believe later in 2021).

Both of these apps allow for editing of map layers (in on/offline mode), and can also be [integrated with other Apps](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/reference/integratewithotherapps.htm) (e.g. Survey123).

Comment: So basically, I need ArcGIS Field Maps linked to a survey form using Survey123 and it can be done?
I tried asking in ESRI community forum but I didn't get any reply. I also tried sending an email to ESRI (in my country) still nothing too

Comment: I haven't made the leap to Field Maps yet, but it looks like it supports it's own forms, as well as can be integrated with S123 (for more advanced forms). Up until now, I have worked on projects that have some proposed sample location(s) that field-teams click on in Collector, and the popup provides a link to an S123 form that, when clicked, opens the S123 form/app with certain form fields pre-populated (e.g. location-ID). Check out preparing an editable layer here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/field-maps/android/help/prepare-an-editable-layer.htm

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. As I understand it I need a Creator user type (ArcGIS online) , Field Worker, Editor, Viewer and their related apps (Field Maps, S123, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You may try ODK ONA. It is an interface platform between the two. You can build form in ONA and export it to ODK app. for field collection and send it back to ONA for visualisations, editing and further manipulation. Make it a trial because I had used it on several occasions to train students and enumerators on the field data collection